# Not able to register a service as Eureka Client

Tags: spring, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm trying to register a Microservice as Eureka Client in order to discover other Microservices, however, I follow the tutorial but nothing shows up in the Eureka Server. Below are code snippets:

1. My `demo` application: a spring boot application running on `localhost:9001`, I want it become a Eureka Client, i.e., register itself as an instance and meanwhile has ability to discover other instances (I used the generic `@EnableDiscoveryClient`annotation and Spring Netflix Eureka is on the classpath):

   ```
   @RestController
   @SpringBootApplication
   @EnableDiscoveryClient
   public class DemoApplication {

   @RequestMapping("/") 
   String home() {
       return "This is a Demo project";
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);  
   }
   }
   ```
2. application.yml:

   ```
   server:
     port: 9001

   eureka:
     client:
       serviceUrl:
           defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
   ```

The Eureka Server should be no problem since I have another Miscroservice running on `localhost:8080` is successfully registered in the server. Just in case here is the application.yml for the Eureka Server:

```
server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
```

Anyone see any problems here?

Answer (score 9):

**The important thing is select the right import**. I lost hours before realizing that:

This is the **bare** dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

This is the **starter pack** dependency wanted in most case:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

If you import the bare dependency, no errors or logs will show up but the service will not register to Eureka server.

*Bottom line, make sure to double double check the dependencies: maybe you need the "starter pack" dependency for a Spring boot component.*

Answer (score 4):

Problem solved, I didn't include dependency 'com.netflix.eureka:eureka-client:1.1.147' in my build.gradle.

Comment: You should use the spring cloud dependency rather adding netflix directly

Answer (score 4):

Do the following in pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

In Spring boot configuration do the following:

@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication

public class ServiceApplication

Comment: @EnableDiscoveryClient is not needed in Spring Cloud Finchley and later

Answer (score 1):

```
service.application.properties
spring.application.name=rating-data-service
server.port=8083
eureka.client.eureka-server-port=8761 // on which port server is running
#eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
#eureka.client.fetch-registry=false

server.application.properties

server.port=8761
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Add above lined in your pom.xml and if you are using gradle use below code :

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-eureka', version: '1.4.6.RELEASE'
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside add pom.xml **spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client**

Answer (score 0):

Client build.gradle needs to be somewhat like below one

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.2.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "Hoxton.SR1")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

application.properties file of client should contain following content -

```
spring.application.name=movie-catalog-service // Your service name
server.port=8081 // on which port you are running
eureka.client.eureka-server-port=8761 // on which port server is running
```

Eureka Server build.gradle needs to be somewhat like below one

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.5.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "Hoxton.SR3")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

application.properties of Eureka Server file should be somewhat like this

```
server.port=8761 // port on which server is running
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

**Reference :** https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/

Answer (score 0):

If we include both `starter` one and without starter as seen in dependency tree `netflix-eureka-client` is missing `eureka-client` itself.

So, adding missing dependency make sense. I think `netflix-eureka-client` should depend `eureka-client` normally, but not for some reason :)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.netflix.eureka</groupId>
        <artifactId>eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `@EnableEurekaServer` and this dependencies for eureka application:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And use `@EnableEurekaClient` for eureka client applications with dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.netflix.eureka</groupId>
        <artifactId>eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And say for client application where is eureka located

```
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWZwj.png)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my issue was solved by upgrading the spring-cloud-dependencies.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

I changed `spring-cloud.version` from `<spring-cloud.version>2021.0.4</spring-cloud.version>` to `<spring-cloud.version>2022.0.0-RC2</spring-cloud.version>`