# Spring Microservice not connecting to Eureka

Tags: java, spring, netflix-eureka

I am trying to connect my microservice with Eureka.

I have added annotation `@EnableDiscoveryClient` to the main class:

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

I am using next dependency in the `build.gradle`:

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client', version: '2.0.1.RELEASE'
```

Finally, I have added config to `application.yml`

```
  eureka:
    client:
      serviceUrl:
        defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
  spring:
    application.name: receipt-processing-microservice
```

And, as you can suggest,  it does not work. I the logs I do not see any log with the tag `DiscoveryChannel` or `Eureka`

Comment: Have you connected to eureka to check the list of services? http://localhost:8761/#/

Comment: Yes, and service is not in the list of the registered services.

Comment: and your not getting any errors or exceptions ? If your not getting errors and your not seeing it registered ... i would guess something with your configuration might be wrong. Maybe your eureka client code is never run ... do you have @EnableDiscoveryClient for example ? Which guide are you using ? I had a look at https://piotrminkowski.wordpress.com/2018/04/26/quick-guide-to-microservices-with-spring-boot-2-0-eureka-and-spring-cloud/

Comment: Yes, I do not see any error or exception. I even tried to set wrong `defaultZone` uri to erureka and still no information in logs, error or exception. I have tried to add `@EnableDiscoveryClient` and `@EnableEurekaClient`, none of them helps. Seems like indeed, eureka code is never run, but I do not understand why! I have used several guides, and the first one was from https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/

Comment: Problem was fixed after I updated spring boot version in build.gradle.

Comment: Check again in pom xml, try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36605508/not-able-to-register-a-service-as-eureka-client

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are missing part of the configuration?

I have the following and everything works perfectly:

```
#Eureka configuration
eureka.client.enabled=true
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=${EUREKA_SERVICE_URL:http://admin:admin@localhost:7995}/eureka/
eureka.client.healthcheck.enabled=true
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=true
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=true
eureka.instance.leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds=15
eureka.instance.leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds=30
```

you can give it a try with some more parameters to see what happens.

Also, do check the list of services in eureka web-ui in case it's just a console log issue: see  localhost:8761/# .

Comment: I have added all of the parameters you listed and It did not help.

Comment: Checking localhost:8761/# is so obvious that I did not write about that. Eureka console, also, do not have any information about my service.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the debug logs. You will be getting lots of information ( which you can redirect to a file) and try looking what is happening underneath - especially after the container startup and when the discovery client is getting initialized. In my case the discovery server is running on 8061 port and my service registration logs are something like below ( see the logs indicating service sending a request to eureka server for registration)

```
DEBUG [employee-service,,,] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'refreshEventListener'
 DEBUG [employee-service,,,] Closing connections idle longer than 30000 SECONDS
 DEBUG [employee-service,,,] Closing connections idle longer than 30000 SECONDS
  INFO [employee-service,,,] Disable delta property : false
  INFO [employee-service,,,] Single vip registry refresh property : null
  INFO [employee-service,,,] Force full registry fetch : false
  INFO [employee-service,,,] Application is null : false
  INFO [employee-service,,,] Registered Applications size is zero : true
  INFO [employee-service,,,] Application version is -1: false
  INFO [employee-service,,,] Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
  Get connection: {}->http://localhost:8061, timeout = 5000
  [{}->http://localhost:8061] total kept alive: 1, total issued: 0, total allocated: 1 out of 200
  Getting free connection [{}->http://localhost:8061][null]
  Stale connection check
  CookieSpec selected: default
  Auth cache not set in the context
  Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
  Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
  Attempt 1 to execute request
  Sending request: GET /eureka/apps/ HTTP/1.1
   >> "GET /eureka/apps/ HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
   >> "Accept: application/json[\r][\n]"
   >> "DiscoveryIdentity-Name: DefaultClient[\r][\n]"
   >> "DiscoveryIdentity-Version: 1.4[\r][\n]"
   >> "DiscoveryIdentity-Id: 192.168.28.145[\r][\n]"
   >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip[\r][\n]"
   >> "Host: localhost:8061[\r][\n]"
   >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
   >> "User-Agent: Java-EurekaClient/v1.9.2[\r][\n]"
   >> "[\r][\n]"
  >> GET /eureka/apps/ HTTP/1.1
  >> Accept: application/json
  >> DiscoveryIdentity-Name: DefaultClient
  >> DiscoveryIdentity-Version: 1.4
  >> DiscoveryIdentity-Id: 192.168.28.145
  >> Accept-Encoding: gzip
  >> Host: localhost:8061
  >> Connection: Keep-Alive
  >> User-Agent: Java-EurekaClient/v1.9.2
  Get connection: {}->http://localhost:8061, timeout = 5000
  [{}->http://localhost:8061] total kept alive: 0, total issued: 1, total allocated: 1 out of 200
  No free connections [{}->http://localhost:8061][null]
  Available capacity: 49 out of 50 [{}->http://localhost:8061][null]
  Creating new connection [{}->http://localhost:8061]
   << "HTTP/1.1 200 [\r][\n]"
   << "Content-Encoding: gzip[\r][\n]"
   << "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
   << "Content-Length: 549[\r][\n]"
   << "Date: Tue, 28 Aug 2018 06:48:14 GMT[\r][\n]"
   << "[\r][\n]"
  Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 
  << HTTP/1.1 200 
  << Content-Encoding: gzip
  << Content-Type: application/json
  << Content-Length: 549
  << Date: Tue, 28 Aug 2018 06:48:14 GMT
  Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
   << "[0x1f][0x8b][0x8][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x9d]S[0xd1][0x8e][0xda]0[0x10][0xfc][0x17][0xeb][0x1e]![0x10][0x8]4[0x97][0xa7];[0x91][0xa8][0x8a][0xda][0x3]D[0xca]UUU![0xd7]Y[0x88]U[0xc7][0x8e]l[0x87]k[0x84][0xf8][0xf7][0xae][0x93][0x86][0x96]SQ[0xd5]*[0xf][0x89]wg[0xd7];3[0x9b][0x13][0xa1]U%8[0xa3][0x96]+iHt"G[0xd0][0xc6]}[0xef]v9[0x8]KID|2p([0x8c][0x14][0xd4][0x14]L[0xe5][0x80][0xc1][0xed]z[0xe7][0xef][0xba]D_N[0xa2][0xcf]'"i[0xe9][0xd2][0xc9][0xd3][0xfa][0xfd][0xea]S[0x92][0xc][0xb3]d[0xf3][0x9c].[0x12]Dri,[0x95][0xc]ZXHs[0x4][0xa7][0x9b]4[0x1b].[0xb2][0xb7]C6[0xe3][0x95][0xa6]P%x[0x12]l[0x4]e%T[0x3]04[0xa0][0x8f][0x9c]A[0x14][0x8e][0xef][0xc7][0xd8][0xaa]P[0xc6].[0xbb][0x8b]n[0xd5]v[0xa3][0xdd][0x98][0xa4]z[0xcc]s[0xed][0x98][0xdd]O<[0x1e]z[0x93][0xd0][0xf3][0x83][0x19]fp([[0x9b][0x96][0x1e][0x9e][0x14]j[0xa1]y[0x9e][0x83][0xcc].[0xf1][0xe5][0xbb][0xe5][0xea][0xe3][0x12][0x93][0x95][0xd2][0xd6][0xe9]uG[0xda][0xa9][0x6][0xe4][0x1]$[0xfd]*[0xc0][0x11][0xb2][0xba][0x6]r[0xc6]v[0xc0]j[\r][0xeb]_[0xc8] [0x98]^[0x1][0xf7]T[0x98][0x16][0xc9]T-[0xad]n[0x9c][0x1c][0xfe][0x80][0xe4][0xd4][0xd2][0x5]H[0xb]:[0x95]{[0xe5]j[0x1f][0x98][0xa0][0xc6][\r][0xc0]T[0xe9][0xe8][0xed][0x5][0xff][0xee]!A[0x8e]y/[0xed][0xc5][0xc4][0xc3]][0xc]{Z[0xb][0x1b]_[0xb7][0x18][0xf4][0xc6]<5[0xab][0x17][0xe9]n[0x14]@[\r][0xf4][0xed]5Hx[0xa1]"u[0xf8][0xa3]{g[0xc0][0xf0][0xb6])[0xd2][0xca]k[0xdd][0xba][0xdb][0xc7][0x1c]U[\r][0x7]nl[0x17][0xff][0xc0]K[0xc0][0xeb]K[0xd4][0xda][0x9f]Mg[0xc1]4[0xc][0xe7][0xc1][0xc4][0xf][0xf1][0x6]j[0xec][0xa6]k|[0x1b][0x4][0xe8][0xeb][0xab]6c'\[0xeb][0xf7][0xb6][0xba]U[0x88][0x4]J[0xb0][0xd4][0x9][0xe5][0xe6]/[0xa9][0xa4][0x7]([0x91][0xaf][0xd7][0xf9]B[0xda]M9[0xbb]U)a[0x8d][0xb9][0xad][0x16][0x18]-[0xac][0xad][0xa2][0xd1][0xe8][0xe6][0xc2][0xb9][0xaa][0xd1]e[0xf][0xfe][0xb1][0x8e]2[S[0xab][0xf4][0x88]w[0x8a][0x17]@[0x85]-[0x16][0x5][0xb0]o[0xff][0xd3][0xa5]+[0xc7]>[0xc7]n_[0xa1][0xf5][0xff][0xf5]/A[0xfa]-{[0xfe][0xb][0x8a][0x9b][0x85]R:[0xe7][0x12]][0x93][0x87][0x98][0x1b][0xe6][0xd6][0xbb][0xc9][0x10][0x0][0xfa][0xb2][0x8a][0x9d]k[0xdb][\n]"
   << "[0x85][0x85][0xfc]7[0xf1][0xc9][0x95][0xfa]?a1[0xd7][0xb6][0xf9]3h<[\r][0xdc][0x1f][0xd8]Y[0xdb]Tn[0xf3][0x1e][0xe3]8[0x89][0xc9][0xf9][0xb]>[0xe7][0x1f][0xc1][0x8d][0x8f][0xd8]w[0x4][0x0][0x0]"
  Connecting to localhost:8061
  CookieSpec selected: default
  Auth cache not set in the context
  Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
  Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
  Attempt 1 to execute request
  Sending request: PUT /eureka/apps/EMPLOYEE-SERVICE/aaaa-aaaa-1567.mshome.net:employee-service:8090?status=UP&lastDirtyTimestamp=1535438864034 HTTP/1.1
   >> "PUT /eureka/apps/EMPLOYEE-SERVICE/aaaa-aaa-1567.mshome.net:employee-service:8090?status=UP&lastDirtyTimestamp=1535438864034 HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
   >> "DiscoveryIdentity-Name: DefaultClient[\r][\n]"
   >> "DiscoveryIdentity-Version: 1.4[\r][\n]"
   >> "DiscoveryIdentity-Id: 192.168.28.145[\r][\n]"
   >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip[\r][\n]"
   >> "Content-Length: 0[\r][\n]"
   >> "Host: localhost:8061[\r][\n]"
   >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
   >> "User-Agent: Java-EurekaClient/v1.9.2[\r][\n]"
   >> "[\r][\n]"
  >> PUT /eureka/apps/EMPLOYEE-SERVICE/aaaa-aaa-1567.mshome.net:employee-service:8090?status=UP&lastDirtyTimestamp=1535438864034 HTTP/1.1
  >> DiscoveryIdentity-Name: DefaultClient
  >> DiscoveryIdentity-Version: 1.4
  >> DiscoveryIdentity-Id: 192.168.28.145
  >> Accept-Encoding: gzip
  >> Content-Length: 0
  >> Host: localhost:8061
  >> Connection: Keep-Alive
  >> User-Agent: Java-EurekaClient/v1.9.2
   << "HTTP/1.1 200 [\r][\n]"
   << "Content-Type: application/xml[\r][\n]"
   << "Content-Length: 0[\r][\n]"
   << "Date: Tue, 28 Aug 2018 06:48:14 GMT[\r][\n]"
   << "[\r][\n]"
  Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 
  << HTTP/1.1 200 
  << Content-Type: application/xml
  << Content-Length: 0
  << Date: Tue, 28 Aug 2018 06:48:14 GMT
  Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
  Released connection is reusable.
  Releasing connection [{}->http://localhost:8061][null]
  Pooling connection [{}->http://localhost:8061][null]; keep alive indefinitely
  Notifying no-one, there are no waiting threads
  Jersey HTTP PUT http://localhost:8061/eureka//apps/EMPLOYEE-SERVICE/aaa-aaa-1567.mshome.net:employee-service:8090; statusCode=200
  DiscoveryClient_EMPLOYEE-SERVICE/aaaa-aaa-1567.mshome.net:employee-service:8090 - Heartbeat status: 200
```

Answer (score -2):

changed config-server port to 8888 in application.yml file.

```
server:
  port: 8888
```